# Setting up AndroidStudio for ReactNative on Windows

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, react-native

everybody,
Yesterday I Installed everything necessary to develop and run an Android app with React Native on Windows: I updated my node.js, installed python2, react-native-cli, Android Studio with AndroidSDK with all tools and all necesary package details how it is described in React Native documentation. Also I set up  Environment variables and path for ANDROID_HOME. Wneh I create a new emulator and run it I received this messages in Android studio: 
"Unable to run 'adb': null"
and
"'C:\Users\User5\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary"

When I create and run a new ReactNative app the building stucks on 97%. Attach imgs bellow. 
When I create and run project on iOS there is no any problem.
I watched a lot of videos and tutorials and nothing seems wrong. But they all are with older version of Android Studio.
Does anybody know where could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

[My React Native very first Android Project stuck building on this stage:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6e5t.png)

Comment: What emulator are you using? Android studio's? Genymotion?

Comment: Android studio. The emulator is working